# Error keeps occurring in custom workflow! HELP!

Tags: 2010, workflow, error

I have a InfoPath form that I have created for users to submit a request for materials. It is linked to a library via SharePoint 2010.

I have a workflow that starts once a user submits the form.

Every time someone submits the form it automatically says there is an error.

I have tried everything I feel! HELP!

The workflow looks like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the history every time:
[image]

Image

Comment: You need to review the server side logs (ULS) for errors.

Comment: How do I review server side logs?

Comment: Get ULS Log viewer and using it you can analyze the logs. Have a look at this guidance. https://sharepoint.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/how-to-troubleshoot-sharepoint-errors-part-2-digging-into-uls/

Answer (score 1):

Can't add a comment, but here might be some things that could cause the error:

- Workflows are executed with the access rights of the user triggering the workflow. Ensure that these users actually have permissions to create and delete elements in the target list. (You can use an impersonation step with the result that the workflow gains access rights of the author of the workflow)
- The workflow cannot resolve some values (e.g current item: created by). Sometimes it helps to just recreate the workflow, since the designer sometimes messes things up.
- The target list has some mandatory fields that are not set while copying the element. This often happens if the target list is modified after the workflow was created.

Error messages from the workflow engine are often too general. Maybe add a comment after every step to see which action specifically causes the workflow to crash.

Comment: I have recreated the workflow many times and it still doesn't work. I have even created a "test" library and linked my info path form to that and recreated the identical workflow and still had the same error come up. I have hit a brick wall with this. Everyone that has access to the form has contribute access. Should it be different?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data types you are trying to move into the other list match the data types from the list item you are copying from.  It is always best in my opinion to just create a new list item in the other list instead of copying it.  It is going to do the same as copying, but it will have its own meta information instead of copying the data from the other list item.  This will prevent your items from crashing and will be much more reliable.

So, make sure your data types match, and create new instead of copy.  That should help.